# How to subdivide a non-rectangular face?

Tags: modeling

[image: id]

Hi guys, I am creating a leaf using reference picture, I started from one vertex and kept extruding until I got the entire outline of leaf. Then I selected all vertices and press F to fill them with a face. Now I want to subdivide the face as I want to sculpt/bend it. But pressing W->Subdivide doesn't do anything, probably because the face is irregular and not rectangular. Any workaround this?
Thank you!

Comment: Try to fill with "Grid Fill" and "Bridge Edge Loops" or you can try the Remesh modifier.

Comment: yes subdivide will create additional vertices between the border vertices but it won't cut through the leaf, you should create some edges through the leaf with join (J) or with the knife tool (K), the subdivide